# How to nicely align chemfig structures in table?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, tabularx, chemfig, threeparttable

I am trying to place a molecular structure (chemfig) in a table give as shown in the figure. However, the structure takes up vertical space from the next row, even after using multirows (see MWE). How to place the structure in the table such that it is nicely aligned in the cell?

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[onecolumn, 12 pt, doublespace, fullpage, letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{chemfig}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Fuel properties of $iso$-cetane}
\label{tab:ap_fuel_property_iso_cetane}
\begin{tabularx}{1.0\textwidth}{lcc}
\toprule
Test                                                   & Result & Method                      \\
\toprule
\multirow{2}{*}{Chemical structure}                    &        &
\multirow{2}{*}
{
    \begin{minipage}{0.33\textwidth}
        \setbondstyle{line width=1pt}\chemfig{
           % 1
        -[:270,0.75]% 2
              (
        -[:210,0.75]% 3
        -[:150,0.75]% 4
                  (
            -[:210,0.75]% 6
                  )
                  (
            -[:150,0.75]% 7
                  )
         -[:90,0.75]% 5
              )
    -[:330,0.75]% 8
     -[:30,0.75]% 9
              (
      -[:112.5,0.75]% 10
              )
              (
       -[:67.5,0.75]% 11
              )
    -[:330,0.75]% 12
     -[:30,0.75]% 13
              (
         -[:90,0.75]% 14
              )
              (
         -[:30,0.75]% 16
              )
    -[:330,0.75]% 15
}
    \end{minipage}
}                                                                                             \\
                                                       &        &                             \\
Molecular weight [\si{\kilogram\per\mol}]              & 114.2  &                             \\
Density [\si{\kilogram\per\cubic\metre}]               & 690  &                             \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want? No `multirow` – a simple `\addlinespace`. I also loaded the `caption` package, to have a decent spacing between above caption and table:

```
\documentclass[onecolumn, 12 pt, doublespace, fullpage, letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{multirow, caption}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{chemfig}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Fuel properties of $iso$-cetane}
\label{tab:ap_fuel_property_iso_cetane}
\begin{tabularx}{1.0\textwidth}{lcc}
\toprule
Test & Result & Method \\
\toprule
Chemical structure & &
    \begin{minipage}{0.33\textwidth}
        \setbondstyle{line width=1pt}\chemfig{
           % 1
        -[:270,0.75]% 2
              (
        -[:210,0.75]% 3
        -[:150,0.75]% 4
                  (
            -[:210,0.75]% 6
                  )
                  (
            -[:150,0.75]% 7
                  )
         -[:90,0.75]% 5
              )
    -[:330,0.75]% 8
     -[:30,0.75]% 9
              (
      -[:112.5,0.75]% 10
              )
              (
       -[:67.5,0.75]% 11
              )
    -[:330,0.75]% 12
     -[:30,0.75]% 13
              (
         -[:90,0.75]% 14
              )
              (
         -[:30,0.75]% 16
              )
    -[:330,0.75]% 15
}
    \end{minipage}
 \\
\addlinespace
Molecular weight [\si{\kg\per\mol}] & 114.2 & \\
Density [\si{\kilogram\per\cubic\m}] & 690 & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]